# RPi3b wlan0 not receiving DHCP lease when WPA2-PSK is on

Tags: pi-3b+, dhcp

RaspberryPi 3 Model B v1.2
Raspbian Buster Desktop (February 2020)

Issue: Cannot get DHCP lease for wlan0 when WiFi network has WPA2-PSK (AES 128) enabled. Running the WiFi without any security allows a DHCP lease and internet connection.

Router: Linksys WRT3200ACM running DD-WRT v3.0-r41328 std (10/15/19)

DHCP settings:

[image: DHCP settings]

WiFi (2.4GHz) settings:
[image: Wifi settings]

WiFi Security settings:
[image: Wifi security]

***On the RaspberryPi:***

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
    ssid="Casa de Caymus"
    psk="*********"
}
```

/etc/dhcpcd.conf:

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# wlan0
#interface wlan0
#static ip_address=192.168.1.55/24
#static routers=192.168.1.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# Most distributions have NTP support.
#option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
#slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
slaac private

# Example static IP configuration:
#interface eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
#static routers=192.168.0.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1

# It is possible to fall back to a static IP if DHCP fails:
# define static profile
#profile static_eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.1.23/24
#static routers=192.168.1.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
```

/etc/network/interfaces: (untouched by me)

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

ifconfig wlan0:

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.128.153  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        ether b8:27:eb:ec:fe:51  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4357  bytes 924511 (902.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 730  bytes 61811 (60.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

iwconfig wlan0:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Casa de Caymus"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 24:F5:A2:2F:B5:DB
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Turning off WPA2 on the WiFi network allows wlan0 to function correctly, receive IP address from DHCP, reach internet, etc.

Attempting to define a static IP using dhcpcd.conf does "set" the IP from the 169.254.128.153 (bad lookup) to 192.168.1.55, but gateway (192.168.1.1) or internet isn't ping-able, and I never see the RPi in my connections list on the router.

With WPA on, it just can't handle it. I've got nothing fancy in my DD-WRT setup at all, and no other device has *any* issue connecting. Any ideas?

Oh and eth0 works just fine when I do connect it, but this RPi needs WiFi working.

Quick edit to add some syslog entries from DD-WRT, looks like there's *some* communication happening here, but no true connection?

```
Mar 1 17:59:06 janus daemon.info hostapd: ath1: STA b8:27:eb:ec:fe:51 MLME: auth request, signal -58 (Accepted)
Mar 1 17:59:06 janus daemon.info hostapd: ath1: STA b8:27:eb:ec:fe:51 MLME: assoc request, signal -58 (Accepted)
Mar 1 17:59:06 janus daemon.info hostapd: ath1: STA b8:27:eb:ec:fe:51 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 2)
Mar 1 17:59:06 janus daemon.info hostapd: ath1: STA b8:27:eb:ec:fe:51 RADIUS: starting accounting session 1B4CEF1FD7FF63EE
Mar 1 17:59:06 janus daemon.info hostapd: ath1: STA b8:27:eb:ec:fe:51 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
Mar 1 17:59:12 janus daemon.info hostapd: ath1: STA b8:27:eb:ec:fe:51 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
```

**EDIT (03/03/20):**

Output of `sudo dhclient -v wlan0`:

```
Listening on LPF/wlan0/b8:27:eb:ec:fe:51
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/b8:27:eb:ec:fe:51
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

And just to confirm that eth0 has no issues with DHCP, here's the output of `sudo dhclient -v eth0`:

```
Listening on LPF/eth0/b8:27:eb:b9:ab:04
Sending on   LPF/eth0/b8:27:eb:b9:ab:04
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.124 from 192.168.1.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.124 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of 192.168.1.124 from 192.168.1.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound to 192.168.1.124 -- renewal in 42713 seconds.
```

In addition, my router's syslog does **not** have any logs of the DCHPREQUEST or the DHCPDISCOVER from wlan0's MAC addr. 
However I *can* see the MAC is connected to wireless: 
[image: wireless]

Comment: perhaps you've got the password wrong - any "unusual" characters in the password? If so, have you considered using a wpa_passphrase to generate a WPA PSK and instead?

Comment: The WiFi appears to be connected. Try to renew leases with
 `sudo dhclient -v wlan0` and post the result of negotiation if this fails.

Comment: Also, add the `dhcpcd.conf`.

Comment: Output of `sudo dhclient -v wlan0`: https://gist.github.com/seanmuth/1cf550821e67a3526eb5e533ee2e06ea

Comment: @M.Rostami my `dhcpcd.conf` is already posted above

Comment: @JaromandaX no it's an alpha-numeric without special chars, and I've entered it in 20+ times now

Comment: I think you didn't understand that. Please add the output of this command: `cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

Comment: @M.Rostami the output, from `cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf,` is already posted in the main post